# Mootools when using For(...in Array) problem

Tags: javascript, mootools

This problem been there for couple years.

I am writing some plugins for a Forum engine called Discuz, I use a lot of Mootools for my own projects. When I plug Mootools into this forum Engine(discuz) things went crazy...

After I did some debugging last year, I found that the problem is that Mootools prototype a lot of core elements, including Array, And, on the other hand, this forum engine uses a lof of For(i in Array) Loop for 'array'. Which will certainly cause problem because

```
for(i in [1,2,3,4,5]) console.log(i);  //0,1,2,3,4 the keys in this array 

**WITH MOOTOOLS
for(i in [1,2,3,4,5]) console.log(i);
//OUTPUT 0,1,2,3,4,$family,$constructor,pop,push,reverse,shift,sort,splice.......
```

Last time i use a parser to change all for(i in array) loop to add an 'if item.hasOwnProperty()' to by pass those prototypes 
But i think this is a very bad work-around cause u know, cause more problems...new versions, bug up their codes...etc

I wonder if there is work around to slove this problem? without touching any of this forum engine's js code, and also use Mootools?

**I know that using For(..in ) for Array is bad, but my question is i dont want to touch this forum engine's javascript codes, i just want a solution to over load the problem**

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you know that the `for-in` statement is highly discouraged to **iterate** over array objects, its purpose is to **enumerate** object properties, if you use simple sequential loops, you will have less problems (they are also faster than `for-in`). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript prototype For...in Iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036097/javascript-prototype-for-in-iterators)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `hasOwnProperty()` as you mentioned. I'm not sure why you think this would cause more problems, indeed with a `for(x in y)` loop I'd be inclined to use `hasOwnProperty()` by default and only omit it for special cases.

Having said that, I wouldn't use a `for(x in y)` loop on an array. It's generally better to use a standard `for(i=0; i<y.length; i++)` loop which will of course ignore all the non-numeric properties. (Except perhaps if you know you've got non-consecutive array indexes, in which case `for(x in y)` will skip the unused indexes, but even in that case I'd probably still use a standard `for` and test for `undefined` within the loop.)

**UPDATE:** OK, I get it now. Your work-around to insert the `hasOwnProperty()` is the best solution I can think of if you want to keep using MooTools. Should be *reasonably* safe to insert it just after the closing `)` of the `for`: you shouldn't need to check for existing `{}` brackets or add your own.

Answer (score 0):

Some newer browsers [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) ways to make all those extra properties (family, constructor, etc) be not enumerable, so they don't appear in the for-in loops.

However, if you want to be able to support the old browsers as well I think you are out of luck: for-in is hardwired syntax so you wont be able to monkey-patch it. (Anyway, the magic find-replace seems to have worked...)

Comment: `object.hasOwnProperty(propertyString)` is quite well-supported, and can be used to avoid issues with `for .. in` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Mootools extends `Array.prototype` and maybe even `Object.prototype`, which can interfere with `for .. in` loops, which enumerate all properties, even those that exist in the object because they appear upwards on the prototype chain. Therefore, test if the property is a direct property of the object before using it:

```
for(i in a)
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log(i);
```

Comment: The OP already does that. He just doesn't like having to modify the code since it comes from another library.