# Iterate through associative array using sequential for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a lot of data stored in associative array.

```
array = {'key':'value'};
```

How to loop throught an array like this using an normal for loop and not a loop like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HzLhe/

I don't want to use for-in because of this problems:
[Mootools when using For(...in Array) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034837/mootools-when-using-for-in-array-problem)

Comment: Why don't you like `for .. in` loop?

Comment: why not using for..in loop ..?

Comment: It is messing with Mototools!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034837/mootools-when-using-for-in-array-problem

Comment: @Jacob that is because you have to use the `.hasOwnProperty` method to filter out the prototype chains properties

Comment: @Jacob You are using object and not array. These elements are different in JavaScript. `for .. in` loop is the best to iterate objects.

Comment: I know it is the best but I have to use a different way. Is it possible?

Comment: @Jacob You said you don't want to use it because there is a mootools problem. The mootools problem is only for arrays (which you should never iterate with for..in to begin with), not for plain objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this isn't an array. This is a JavaScript object. To iterate over it, you will have to use the for...in loop. But to filter out the other properties, youw ill have to use `hasOwnProperty`.

Example:

```
var obj={'key1': 'value1','key2':'value2'};

for (var index in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(index);
    console.log(obj[index]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/HzLhe/3/

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript does not have the concept of associative arrays. Instead you simply have an object with enumerable properties, so use a for..in loop to iterate through them. As stated above you may also want to perform a check with `hasOwnProperty` to ensure that you're not performing operations on inherited properties.

```
for (var prop in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log(obj[prop]);
    }
}
```