# How to convert Associative array to a simple string array of values in javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

So I want to convert this array retrieved from a database to just an array of string values:

Array:[{"userid":"c"},{"userid":"d"}]

Expected results:["c","d"]

Comment: if you are a programmar then try to google it first...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through associative array using sequential for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809366/iterate-through-associative-array-using-sequential-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `map` function

```
result = myArray.map(function(item){ return item.userid; })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this conversions on javascript side, you should keep in mind, that if there would be a lot of items, the performance might be rather bad. May be it would be better to change logick of gathering the first array.

For conversion you could try this:

```
Data = [{"userid":"c"},{"userid":"d"}];
arr = [];
for(i in Data){
   arr.push(Data[i].userid);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be

```
const results = myArray.map(item => item.userId);
```